# Changes not reflecting when deploying to IIS Web Server (.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am fairly new in .Net Framework. I am attempting to publish/deploy my changes on IIS Web Windows Server.

The change was only on **Login.aspx.cs** file. Published method used is FileSystem, and I copy the files to production server.

I have been doing trial and errors since the behaviour differs every time. Once I added the file path on IIS and check them on the browser, these are the behaviour:

- It shows for the first couple of tries, then the changes made is gone.
- The changes do not show at all
- It works for a couple of hours. And when I check on them again, changes is gone.

I already tried restarting the server, IIS reset/restart, removed Temporary ASP.NET Files. But it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: 1) What if you clear browser cache? Keep in mind things are not only cached on server side, and different browsers use different strategies. 2) How many server(s) are you using? 3) Is there anything else between the browser/server? Proxy and CDN are very common and they add extra caches.

Comment: Well, during the publish the web server should be stopped. And I assume that you do a full re-publish, and not JUST try to copy the .cs file, right? And are the code changes not working, or is this css and JavaScript changes? After  you publish, start the web server then make sure you try a ctrl-f5 in your browser to force a re-load of the script and css files.

Comment: @LexLi I use different browsers, and Incognito mode. The server is connected to Azure

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yes, I used all the published files on server. How do I sop the web server?

Comment: What is “connected to Azure”? So this server is a virtual machine hosted in Azure? Does the issue remain if you open a browser on the server itself?

Comment: @LexLi Yes, it is a VM.. and yes, I use the browse on the server to test.

Comment: see my answer on how to stop the IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, I often find that some .dlls "stick" in memory. And this EVEN includes when I just stop the one site. So, I recommend that you stop the IIS web server. You then delete all files in the given site's folder. You then copy over the new site, and then start the server.

Of course, be careful in above. While your web config "should" be correctly transformed, some sites don't necessary do this. And also some sites do have a folder for the security certificate that also in a folder (so, just a FYI here).

So, to stop IIS, then launch IIS, and right click on the server node, NOT the site note.

eg this:

[image]

So, you are to stop the IIS server as per above, and not JUST stop the site, since as stated, some .dll's can continue to be cached.

So, right click on the IIS server node above, stop the site. Then delete everything in the site's folder, copy in the new site, and then right click on the IIS node as per above, and choose start.

Comment: Thank you. I have been doing this, as well as stopping the Application Pool connected to my site, which led me to finding out the issue.

Turns out the new DLL of my application is being deleted on Temporary ASP.NET file. The one being used is the DLL on the Virtual Directory under my application. I had to copy the new DLL file and placed it on the VD. 

Thanks for taking time answering. Cheers!